# scala: data structure for multiple-root tree or forest

Tags: scala, graph, tree

I am in search of a good data structure for my requirement:

- Support multiple roots.
- Should have links to parent and children.

Assuming each `Node` can be uniquely identified, I have come up with a following data structure which seems a bit immature.

```
case class Node[T](data: T, children: List[Node[T]], parents: List[Node[T]])

class Forest[T](val roots: List[Node[T]]) {

  // other helper methods to create the Forest
}

object Forest {
  def apply[T](list: List[T]): Forest[T] = {
    val roots = for (l <- list) yield Node[T](l, List.empty[Node[T]], List.empty[Node[T]])
    new Forest[T](roots)
  }
}
```

Does anyone have better suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you check out [Graph for Scala](http://www.scala-graph.org/).  The library isn't being very actively developed, but the basic functionality doesn't need it and once you get used to the way it traverses nodes, you get a lot of functionality without much effort.  (It might take a little thought to best fit the parent/child relationship into the graph; you could make a directed graph to represent that, or two graphs one in each direction, etc.)

Otherwise, the basics of what you have now is missing one detail--how do you actually create the forest?  Right now, a node is immutable with immutable lists of parents and children, which means that the parents and children of every node must be created before the node is, which means...uh-oh.

You can solve this by adding an extra layer of indirection (have lists of node IDs and a map associating IDs with actual nodes), or by adding mutability somewhere (generally a little iffy in case classes, but in this case maybe it's what you need).

And then, of course, you need a bunch of methods to actually do something useful with the forest and provide higher-level ways of constructing it.

Comment: Yes I missed the part of creating mutable list for parents and children, should have declared them as `var` instead of `val`. +1 for the link.